# How can I format a SD card from my phone?

Tags: sd-card

I've formatted my microSD 32 GB Sandisk SDHC 3, Class 10 with SDFormatter which I was using on my raspi3 apparently with no issues. But now I can't read it on my pc (Win7) or any other one. I've tried with a SD adapter and with USB adapter with the same results: it plugs and unplugs constantly.

When I put it on my phone (Aquaris BQ M5) I format the card correctly, I keep getting the same issues when connecting the card "directly" to the pc BUT if I keep the card on the phone and connect the phone on MTP I can copy and delete and open files without problems... but I don't know how to give it format since there or use DISkPART or something similar.

How could I properly format my SD to install Raspbian on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to format your mSD for installing Raspbian; instead, you simply "flash" the Raspbian image file: that simply writes the image file to the mSD from start to end. I highly recommend using [Etcher](https://etcher.io) which is available for Linux, OS X, and Windows. It can be run without installing, is easy to use, and checks that the image was flashed correctly.

Comment: I've bought a different mSD today: it seems that I have a faulty reader AND two faulty front USB connectors. So I guess my question lacks the facts to be a proper question as I don't have any certainty of why any of this happened.

So I guess I should delete the question.

And btw, thanks for etcher.io, I was going thru the SD Format + Win 32 Img process.

Comment: Your question is still valid: how do I format my mSD for Raspbian? And the answer is: you don't need to. I would suggest keeping the question and also your feedback comments; you should even add them as a note to the footer of your qiestion.